# Access domain (and port) URL in settings.py file while in localhost development

Tags: python, django, development-environment, django-settings

How do you dynamically access the domain name URL in the `settings.py` file of Django? (ie  "http://localhost:8000")

I am trying to overwrite a package CDN while the internet is unavailable during development, and want to point to the local file in the `static` files directory.   While os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "path/to/local.file") should work, it is context-dependent as to which app/url (ie "http://localhost:8000/app/static/css/bootstrap.min.css
"), and not just the main domain with the static file location appended to the starting server with `./manage.py runserver 0:8000` (ie " http://localhost:8000/static/css/bootstrap.min.css").

Notes:

- Because this is in the `settings.py`, I can't load any apps or `reverse` because of the error `*** django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`
- I am not in a template, so I can't use the `static` url
- statically defining it won't allow for different port loadings when starting via `./manage.py runserver 0:8000`
- `settings.py` is basically a python module, but how can you get the domain within it?

Basically in the `settings.py` file:

```
# If in local dev
if "RDS_DB_NAME" not in os.environ:
    # the setting for the package I am pointing to a local version
    BOOTSTRAP5 = {
        "css_url": {
            ### dynamically get domain here ###
            # "href": os.path.join(LOCAL_DIR, "static/css/bootstrap.min.css"),
            "href": "static/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the domain in `settings.py`. When you run `./manage.py runserver 0:8000` you are telling Django to listen on port 8000 of whatever localhost is. But you can't tell from this machine which requests are going to come to this machine. For instance, you could have DNS configured to send `www.domain1.com` and `www.domain2.com` to come to this machine which looks like localhost from your perspective. So you can't know "domain" until a requests comes in.

Your machine does however have a local machine name which you could figure out from `settings.py`. Different OSes do this differently but on Macs you can get it with `scutil --get LocalHostName` and on other Unixes you can `cat /etc/hostname`.

Chris Curvey is right that the canonical way to differentiate between environments is with different settings files. Most devs differentiate between local and production environments but you are proposing a third: local with no internet access.

There are 2 steps to making this work.

### Detect when to use the "local with no internet" environment.

The du jour way (and easiest way, IMO) to do this is with an environment variable. There are lots of ways to do this. You could, for instance, set `LOCAL_NO_INTERNET=True` in the environment and then check that variable anytime you need to do something special in your code.

If you really need to detect this automatically you could:

1. Query for the local machine's name (machine name, not domain, as described above)
2. Check if the name matches your local dev machine (so that you don't do this thing in prod, etc.)
3. Check if you don't have internet (ping google.com or something and see if it comes back successfully or times out)

I do not recommend this approach; there are many edge cases. Plus you probably can determine for yourself if you would like to be in "local with no internet" environment and set the environment variable manually.

### Serve cached files usually provided by CDN

I think the easiest way, although a little verbose, is to put an `if` statement in your templates to either target the CDN or your local version (note that you will have to pass `LOCAL_NO_INTERNET` in the context of the view):

```html
{% if LOCAL_NO_INTERNET %}
  <script src="{% static "cdncache/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
{% else %}
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="..." crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
{% endif %}
```

Or you could do something way more complicated here like a middleware to somehow replace references to CDNs.

I would suggest that instead of defining this new "local with no internet" environment you could change your local setup to always assume "local with no internet". The CDN should speed up requests in production but doesn't do you much good in local development compared with always using your own version of those files.

Answer (score -1):

I've never found a way to find out details about the Django listener.

The canonical way to have different settings in different environments is to have different settings files, and then set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable to control which one is used.

Comment: Even with a separate file, how would you access the domain dynamically? `sys.args` has the port, but not the domain...

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear.  If you want the system to behave one way (serve static files from localhost) in development, you can setup a dev_settings.py configured that way.  If you want it to be different in production, you set up a different settings file and use that in production.

Comment: Yes.   That is what I am currently doing.   But in the case of development, when the internet is not working, i want to be able to serve a static version of a CDN library.    But I can't just call `{% static "path to file" %}` like in a template, because I am not in a template.   I can not use an app, because apps aren't loaded.   and the request  has not been generated, so I don't have access to the SITE info or other hostname with port.